# Overflow is not showable

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have a problem with a website I'm trying to make. The problem is, that no matter what I do, I just can't get any scrollbar to get working. The Website is reachable via https://scania01.de/frp/html_twitter/. Is anyone out there who could figure out what's the problem here?

I've already tried to add overflow: auto;, overflow: visible; and overflow: scroll; to the body and to the div.

Hopefully someone can help me!

Greetings,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change or remove the "position: fixed;" property of the .divhome_divtweets class you have in your inline styles. That should bring back the scroll bar.

After going through your code I have some feedback on your CSS:

- Don't add classes to your html tag as this is not allowed
- Also you can't add id's or classes to the head had or any of the tags nested within.
- Avoid styling using html tags such as; div, body, p, span etc.
- You have overridden and/or added styling for elements (eg. body) in multiple locations. This makes it hard to read and debug your code. If you're going to add style to a body or div element for example, then do so in a single CSS file and ovoid overriding it anywhere else.
- Remove redundant and unused CSS
- Move your inline CSS into a CSS file
- I'd also recommend moving the scripts into their own files
- Make use of flexbox and/or CSS grid for positioning your elements

The below snippet is an example of what I mean. I removed all the styles you had in the head tag and moved them into your site_global.css. I also removed the the inline style you had in the text field that is at the top of your page. I added a width=100% for that in the CSS file using the #input_tweet id. I also modified your CSS a bit, as well as removing a lot of it. I kept just enough to maintain the style of your existing page.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.downloadbutton {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: rgb(159, 38, 47);
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #111;
  color: lightgrey;
}

.downloadbuttonclosed {
  cursor: no-drop;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: rgb(102, 24, 30);
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
}

.leftmenu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 235px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: lightslategray;
  border-right: 3px solid rgb(159, 38, 47);
}

.topline {
  height: 35px;
  width: 1430px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 235px;
  background-color: #111;
  color: lightslategray;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(159, 38, 47);
}

.divhome_divtweets {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 82%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: lightgrey;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: rgb(159, 38, 47);
}

.tweets {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgb(159, 38, 47);
}

.headlinetweetinput {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  width: 82%;
  color: lightgrey;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: rgb(159, 38, 47);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

#input_tweet {
  width: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: block;
  src: url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.eot);
  src: url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.woff2) format("woff2"), url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.woff) format("woff"), url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.ttf) format("truetype"), url(https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/webfonts/free-fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg")
}

.fa,
.far,
.fas {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
}

.fa-comment:before {
  content: "\f075"
}

.fa-comment-alt:before {
  content: "\f27a"
}

.fa-comment-dollar:before {
  content: "\f651"
}

.fa-comment-dots:before {
  content: "\f4ad"
}

.fa-comment-medical:before {
  content: "\f7f5"
}

.fa-comment-slash:before {
  content: "\f4b3"
}

.fa-comments:before {
  content: "\f086"
}

.fa-comments-dollar:before {
  content: "\f653"
}

.fa-heart:before {
  content: "\f004"
}

.fa-heart-broken:before {
  content: "\f7a9"
}

.fa-heartbeat:before {
  content: "\f21e"
}
```

```html
<html lang="de-DE">

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="2018.0.0.379">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/308ca0f35e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <title>Homepage</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site_global.css?crc=444006867">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="leftmenu" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
    <p style="font-size: 50px; color: white; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 30px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Firebird</p>
    <div style="padding-top: 40px; display:none">
      <a style="background-color: black;" class="leftitem" id="lefthome" onmouseover="mouseOverLeft0()" onmouseout="mouseOutLeft0()" onclick="changesite(1)"><i class="fas fa-door-closed" style="padding-right: 7px;" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a> <br><br>
      <a class="leftitem" id="left1" onmouseover="mouseOverLeft1()" onmouseout="mouseOutLeft1()" onclick="changesite(2)"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag" style="padding-right: 12px;" aria-hidden="true"></i> Meine Apps</a> <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topline" unselectable="on" onselectstart="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
    <div style="padding-right: 35px; padding-top: 9px;" align="right">
      <!--<p style="padding-left: 20px; float:left;"><i style="padding-right: 5px;" class="fas fa-user-alt"></i> Assistant Chief | Micheal Charter</p>-->
      <a id="close" onmouseover="mouseOverClose1()" onmouseout="mouseOutClose1()" onclick="close()"><i class="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="divlogin" style="line-height: 1; display: none;">
    <div class="headline">
      <h1><i class="fas fa-star-of-life" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</h1>
      <br>
      <label for="input_username" style="font-size:20px;">Benutzername:</label>
      <input style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;" type="text" oninput="checkbutton()" id="input_username" name="input_username"><br>
      <label for="input_pwd" style="font-size:20px;">Passwort:</label>
      <input style="font-size:20px; margin-left:57px;" type="text" id="input_pwd" oninput="checkbutton()" name="input_pwd"><br><br>
      <button id="login_button" onclick="login()" class="downloadbuttonclosed" style="float: right;">Bestätigen</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="divhome" style="line-height: 1; display: block;">
    <div class="headlinetweetinput">
      <h1 id="input_tweet_header" style="font-size:20px;margin-bottom:20px;">Schreibe einen Tweet!</h1>
      <textarea oninput="checktweetbutton()" id="input_tweet" name="input_tweet" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
      <button style="margin-top:15px;" id="twtbutton" class="downloadbuttonclosed">Tweeten</button>
    </div>
    <div id="home_tweets" class="divhome_divtweets">
      <div id="7370207417623680" class="tweets">
        <img style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://image.scania01.de/2020-03-03_19-33-24.png" width="40" height="40">
        <h1 style="display:inline-block;">Scania01</h1><br><br>
        <p style="font-size:17px;">Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das
          ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. </p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(121, 121, 121);text-align: right;">Vor 17 Minuten</p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(196, 50, 60);text-align: left;"><i style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;text-decoration: none;" onclick="likepost('7370207417623680')" class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"> 16</i><i style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;" class="far fa-comment"
            aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      </div>
      <div id="7370207417623686" class="tweets">
        <img style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://image.scania01.de/2020-03-03_19-33-24.png" width="40" height="40">
        <h1 style="display:inline-block;">Scania01</h1><br><br>
        <p style="font-size:17px;">Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das
          ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. </p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(121, 121, 121);text-align: right;">Vor 17 Minuten</p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(196, 50, 60);text-align: left;"><i id="7370207417623686_like" style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;text-decoration: none;" onclick="likepost('7370207417623686_like')" class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"> 16</i><i style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;"
            class="far fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      </div>
      <div id="7370207417623686" class="tweets">
        <img style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://image.scania01.de/2020-03-03_19-33-24.png" width="40" height="40">
        <h1 style="display:inline-block;">Scania01</h1><br><br>
        <p style="font-size:17px;">Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das
          ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. </p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(121, 121, 121);text-align: right;">Vor 17 Minuten</p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(196, 50, 60);text-align: left;"><i id="7370207417623686_like" style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;text-decoration: none;" onclick="likepost('7370207417623686_like')" class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"> 16</i><i style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;"
            class="far fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      </div>
      <div id="7370207417623686" class="tweets">
        <img style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="https://image.scania01.de/2020-03-03_19-33-24.png" width="40" height="40">
        <h1 style="display:inline-block;">Scania01</h1><br><br>
        <p style="font-size:17px;">Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das
          ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet,
          dass das hier mein Tweet ist. Das ist mein Tweet. Ich habe getweetet, dass das hier mein Tweet ist. </p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(121, 121, 121);text-align: right;">Vor 17 Minuten</p>
        <p style="font-size:13px;color:rgb(196, 50, 60);text-align: left;"><i id="7370207417623686_like" style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;text-decoration: none;" onclick="likepost('7370207417623686_like')" class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"> 16</i><i style="cursor:pointer !important;padding-right:10px;"
            class="far fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Other scripts -->

  <!-- RequireJS script -->


  <script>
    var randomtweetinputtextes = ["Was passiert gerade?", "Was geht ab?", "Was möchtest du uns mitteilen?", "Was möchtest du der Welt mitteilen?", "Tweete etwas!", "Schreibe einen Tweet!"]
    var randomtweetinputtexteszahl = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomtweetinputtextes.length)
    document.getElementById("input_tweet_header").innerHTML = randomtweetinputtextes[randomtweetinputtexteszahl]
    document.getElementById("divlogin").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById("divhome").style.display = "block"

    //addtweet("s")

    function tosite(site) {
      if (site == "home") {
        document.getElementById("input_tweet_header").innerHTML = randomtweetinputtextes[randomtweetinputtexteszahl]
        document.getElementById("divlogin").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("divhome").style.display = "block"
      }
    }

    function checkbutton() {
      if (document.getElementById("input_username").value != "" && document.getElementById("input_pwd").value != "") {
        document.getElementById("login_button").classList.remove("downloadbuttonclosed")
        document.getElementById("login_button").classList.add("downloadbutton")
      } else if (true) {
        document.getElementById("login_button").classList.remove("downloadbutton")
        document.getElementById("login_button").classList.add("downloadbuttonclosed")
      }
    }

    function checktweetbutton() {
      console.log(document.getElementById("input_tweet").value.length)
      if (document.getElementById("input_tweet").value.length > 5) {
        document.getElementById("twtbutton").classList.remove("downloadbuttonclosed")
        document.getElementById("twtbutton").classList.add("downloadbutton")
      } else if (true) {
        document.getElementById("twtbutton").classList.add("downloadbuttonclosed")
        document.getElementById("twtbutton").classList.remove("downloadbutton")
      }

    }

    function login() {
      if (true) {
        tosite("home")
      }
    }

    function addtweet(id, userimg, username, tweet, likes, comments) {
      var randomtweetid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999999999)
      console.log(randomtweetid)
    }

    function likepost(id) {
      console.log(id)
      console.log(document.getElementById(id).classList[0])
      //console.log(document.getElementById(id).classList[1])
      if (document.getElementById(id).classList[0] == "far") {
        var newlikes = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML, 10) + 1

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = " " + newlikes
        document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("far")
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add("fas")
        // FIVEM: ADD LIKE
      } else if (document.getElementById(id).classList[0] == "fas") {
        var newlikes = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML, 10) - 1

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = " " + newlikes
        document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("fas")
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add("far")
        // FIVEM: REMOVE LIKE
      } else if (document.getElementById(id).classList[1] == "far") {
        var newlikes = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML, 10) + 1

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = " " + newlikes
        document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("far")
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add("fas")
        // FIVEM: ADD LIKE
      } else if (document.getElementById(id).classList[1] == "fas") {
        var newlikes = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML, 10) - 1

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = " " + newlikes
        document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("fas")
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add("far")
        // FIVEM: REMOVE LIKE
      }
    }


    function mouseOverLeft0() {
      document.getElementById("lefthome").style.color = "CadetBlue";
      document.getElementById("lefthome").style.textDecoration = "none";
      document.getElementById("lefthome").style.cursor = "context-menu";
    }

    function mouseOutLeft0() {
      document.getElementById("lefthome").style.color = "lightslategray";
    }

    function mouseOverLeft1() {
      document.getElementById("left1").style.color = "CadetBlue";
      document.getElementById("left1").style.textDecoration = "none";
      document.getElementById("left1").style.cursor = "context-menu";
    }

    function mouseOutLeft1() {
      document.getElementById("left1").style.color = "lightslategray";
    }

    function mouseOverLeft2() {
      document.getElementById("left2").style.color = "CadetBlue";
      document.getElementById("left2").style.textDecoration = "none";
      document.getElementById("left2").style.cursor = "context-menu";
    }

    function mouseOutLeft2() {
      document.getElementById("left2").style.color = "lightslategray";
    }

    function mouseOverLeft3() {
      document.getElementById("left3").style.color = "CadetBlue";
      document.getElementById("left3").style.textDecoration = "none";
      document.getElementById("left3").style.cursor = "context-menu";
    }

    function mouseOutLeft3() {
      document.getElementById("left3").style.color = "lightslategray";
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I could manage to get the site scrollable through your answer. I'll also change some of your suggestions in my Code.